# Why the time taken to by an iterative algorithm to find the sum of list does not increase uniformly with size?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, performance, time-complexity, processing-efficiency

I wanted to see how drastic is the difference in time complexity between the iterative and recursive approaches to sum an array. So I plotted a 'time' versus 'size of the list' graph for a pretty decent range of values for size(995). What I got was pretty much what I wanted except something unexpected caught my eye.
The graph can be seen here [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWNkf.png)

What's confusing me here are those bumps that the green line suddenly takes only for certain values and then comes back down. Why does that happen?

Here is the code I had written:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import time

def sum_rec(lst): # Sums recursively
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return 0
    return lst[0]+sum_rec(lst[1:])

def sum_iter(lst): # Sums iteratively
    Sum = 0
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        Sum += i
    return Sum

def check_time(lst): # Returns the time taken for both algorithms
    start = time()
    Sum = sum_iter(lst)
    end = time()
    t_iter = end - start
    start = time()
    Sum = sum_rec(lst)
    end = time()
    t_rec = end - start
    return t_iter, t_rec

N = [n for n in range(995)]
T1 = [] # for iterative function
T2 = [] # for recursive function

for n in N: # values on the x-axis
    lst = [i for i in range(n)]
    t_iter, t_rec = check_time(lst)
    T1.append(t_iter)
    T2.append(t_rec)

plt.plot(N,T1)
plt.plot(N,T2) # Both plotted on graph
plt.show()
```

Comment: In order for us to understand what you are asking you have to provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have added the code. I guess it's fine now?

Comment: You're probably seeing spikes of garbage collection. Run the tests hundreds of times and take averages, for example using `timeit`.

Comment: You're not comparing an iterative and recursive implementation of the same thing. The recursive version is building a new list each time, and I guess you've got the graph labels the wrong way round

Comment: The iterative version doesn't use the values in the list at all. How do you know which colour is which on the graph?

Answer (score -1):

I'd say both the algorithms have a linear runtime but the recursive one has a higher constant factor, which causes the steeper slope.

Other than that:-

(1) You're mixing up the two plots.

The iterative one stays grounded while the recursive one increases.

One possible explanation may be that recursive calls make stack entries and require more computational time than iterative calls.

(2) You need to increase the size of the array as small sizes are more likely to cause spikes due to locality of reference.

(3) You need to repeat the experiment over multiple epochs to make sure random spikes due to some other process hogging the resource is distributed evenly.

[image: Effect Of Averaging with constant array size]

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the recursive code looks quadratic because of the O(n) list slicing at each level, and the graphs you've drawn also suggest quadratic. Can you explain what you mean about locality of reference causing spikes? Usually locality of reference is used to mean that the data caches well, which would make it faster, not slower.

Comment: I'm sorry for the uninformed answer. I assumed the array slicing did a pass by reference instead of copying the entire array. It was wrong on my part to make any assumptions. I also assumed that the spikes meant that the locality was gone and the caches had to store the new values. Now that I look back , I don't think that's how caches work.

Comment: Sorry for the very naive and amateurish mistake I did in asking this question. I realize I did mix up the two plots and was thinking the recursive one stays grounded. Thanks for your help and suggestions. Yes, the hogging issue might also be true. I am not very knowledgable about the locality of reference thing, but I am heading to read about it now. Thank you so much. :)